# Run bash script from file with input

Tags: bash

I want to make a simple bash script that makes a for loop over a file with commands and execute those commands, and finishes when an error happens. I have something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line
    output=$(eval $line)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo ok
    else
        echo $output
        break
    fi
    echo
done < summary.txt
```

The problem is that the first command I'm trying to make is a sudo command, so I have to put the password. I tried putting it in the command like

```
sudo -S <<< password <<< Y command
```

with no luck. I've checked that works if I just put it directly without having to read it (not putting it as a string). The thing is that without the loop, the program would be long with no much sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
echo <password> | sudo -S < your command>
```

From `man sudo`

```
   -S, --stdin
                 Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of using the terminal
                 device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.
```

Comment: There is one step missing. After the sudo I need to reply Y. In this case, when it's asked, it answers "abort"

Comment: Do you mean after running sudo command you want to get input from `stdin` ?

Comment: Yes. I need to install something (testing purposes) so I'm doing a sudo apt install. Normally it asks for password and to confirm Y/n, so I need to answer Y

Comment: How then about `echo "<passwd>\nY" | sudo -S ...`, or if you run into timing issues, `(echo <passwd>; sleep 1; echo Y)|sudo -S ...`?

Comment: (echo <passwd>; sleep 1; echo Y)|sudo -S .. solved my problem! Thanks!